# Adding Naming Convention to Existing Database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using sqlalchemy and am trying to integrate alembic for database migrations.

My database currently exists and has a number of ForeignKeys defined without names. I would like to add a naming convention to allow for migrations that affect ForeignKey columns.

I've added the naming convention given here to the top of my models.py file: 
[SQLAlchemy Naming Constraints](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#configuring-constraint-naming-conventions)

```
convention = {
      "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
      "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
      "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
      "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
      "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
              }

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()


DeclarativeBase.metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=convention)

def db_connect():
   return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))

def create_reviews_table(engine):
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

class Review(DeclarativeBase):

    __tablename__ = 'reviews'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    review_id = Column('review_id', String, primary_key=True)
    resto_id = Column('resto_id', Integer, ForeignKey('restaurants.id'),
            nullable=True)
    url = Column('url', String),
    resto_name = Column('resto_name', String)
```

I've set up alembic/env.py as per the tutorial instructions, feeding my model's metadata into target_metadata.

When I run

```
$: alembic current
```

I get the following error: 
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Naming convention including %(constraint_name)s token requires that constraint is explicitly named.

In the docs they say that "This same feature [generating names for columns using a naming convention] takes effect even if we just use the Column.unique flag:" [1](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#configuring-constraint-naming-conventions), so I'm thinking that there shouldn't be a problem (they go on to give an example using a ForeignKey that isn't named too).

Do I need to go back and give all my constraints explicit names, or is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: You say that your database already has ForeignKeys but this approach only seems to work if you create these keys via SQLAlchemy. Otherwise you are currently in a state where SQLAlchemy knows what the name **should** be, but it finds nothing under that name (and maybe sees a different name?). I don't know what SA detects here but you basically need to recreate (or rename?) your foreign keys, indexes, etc.

Comment: In case you didn't post your complete schema, there is a bug with booleans and naming conventions atm: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3067/naming-convention-exception-for-boolean

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 10):

just modify th "ck" in convention to `"ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s"`。it works for me .

refer to [see sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#constraint-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 6):

What this error message is telling you is that you should name constraints explicitly. The constraints it's referring to are Boolean, Enum etc but not foreignkeys nor primary keys.
So go through your table, wherever you have a Boolean or Enum add a name to it. For example:

```
is_active = Column(Boolean(name='is_active'))
```

That's what you need to do.

Comment: Fantastic.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This does not aim to be definitive answer and also fails to answer your immediate technical question, but could it be a "philosophical problem"? Either your SQLAlchemy code is the source of truth as far as the database is concerned, or the RDMS is the source. In front of this a mixed situation, where each of the two have part of it, I would see two avenues:

1. The one that you are exploring: you modify the database's schema to match the SQLAlchemy model and you make your Python code the master. This is the most intuitive, but this *may* not always be possible, both for technical and administrative reasons.
2. Accepting that the RDMS has info that SQLAlchemy doesn't have, but is fortunately not relevant for day-to-day work. Your best chance is to use another migration tool (ETL) that will *reverse engineer* the database before migrating it. After the migration is complete you could give back control of the new instance to SQLAlchemy (which may require some adjustments to the new DB or to the model).

There is no way to tell which approach will work, since both have their own challenges. But I would give some thought to the second method?

Answer (score 1):

I've had some luck altering `naming_convention` back to `{}` in each older migration so that they run with the correct historical context.

Still entirely unsure what kind of interesting side-effects this might have.